# jQuery '#' + data("target") pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen this a bunch:

```
<a href="#" id="trigger" data-target="content">Click me</a>
<div id="content">And something will happen here</div>
```

With JS like this:

```
$("#trigger").click(function(){
  $("#" + $(this).data("target")).hide();
})
```

It looks a little weird to me to be doing this string concatenation to create selectors which are then used to get the target element. Is there a better pattern in Javascript (with jQuery available) for setting up handlers on one element which need to know about another target element?

Comment: It may feel a little awkward but there's nothing wrong with this.

Comment: @j08691 I know it works, looking for some experienced arguments about best practices from people who have maintained larger JS projects.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Why you do string concatenation just store the id with `#`

```
<a href="#" id="trigger" data-target="#content">Click me</a>

$("#trigger").click(function(){
  $($(this).data("target")).hide();
})
```

Similarly you can store any selectors as is in `data-target` say for ex:- `.tab1` etc so that you do not have to perform string concatenation again inside the click or any event.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: is the `$()` around `$(this).data("target")` really necessary?

Comment: @SirDerpington Yes, `this` is a DOM element and does not have a `data` function.  `data` is a function of jquery, so you must use `$` to create a jquery object.

Comment: Another benefit of this approach is that I'm no longer limited to id's. Any selector would work.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use

```
$('#content').modal('toggle');
```

Any where in you're code to initiate the modal show and hide,
You can use even "show"/"hide" functionality directly.

I assume you're using Bootstrap and one of the latest versions of jQuery.

Enjoy !

Comment: this doesn't answer my question.  The question isn't about how to hide or show things with JS, it's about patterns for embedding dynamic selector targets within HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Why not do something like this, a much better approach in my opinion:

```
// Set the target
$("#trigger").data('target', $('#content'));

// Get the target
$("#trigger").click(function(){
  $(this).data("target").hide();
})
```

If you're setting it from the backend, I would include the hash with the attribute value as others have suggested.

```
<a href="#" id="trigger" data-target="#content">Click me</a>

$("#trigger").click(function(){
     var target = $(this).data("target"); 
     $(target).hide();
})
```

Comment: Whenever I've seen this done, the data attribute is used because it is set from the backend.

Comment: Right, I'd like the JS to be generic, so that I can specify targets in my markup and everything flows. I guess the question is really how do we best go from strings in HTML to objects in javascript. Setting data-target to the actual jquery object is ideal, but how to do that generically?

Answer (score 1):

You always have the option to build the selector, looks a bit nicer than concatenating the string inside the selector.

```
$("#trigger").click(function(){
    var selector = "#" + $(this).data("target");
    $(selector).hide();
});
```

A little nicer, not sure if it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would skip the data- completely, thus allowing graceful degradation.

```
<a href="#content" id="trigger" data-target="">Click me</a>
<div id="content">And something will happen here</div>
```

with

```
$("#trigger").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $( $(this).attr("href") ).show();
  // note, i'm purposly not using this.href due to a bug in IE that would return the entire href rather than just the hash
})
```

Answer (score 0):

$(this).attr('data-target', '#myTarget');

this worked for me